# Django: How to make json data readable in django?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

i am trying to retrieve the lastest news from hackernews api, everthing seems to be working fine and when i print the status code, i get Status Code:200. Now i am getting some data but they are not readable this is how there are displayed

```
b'[31349988,31344981,31348529,31344863,31341698,31348097,31347740,31348772,31347286,31348463,31345478,31348316,31345749,31347983,3'
```

and this is code i used to retrieve the data from the api https://hackernews.api-docs.io/

```
def index(request):
    response = requests.get("https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json")
    return render(request, "index.html", {'response': response})
```

this is how they look in the template, instead of displaying the title
[image]

index.html

```
{% story in response %}
   {{ story.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

That API gives an array integer as a response. So I supposed API manipulation error. So plz inform the API creator and get advice from them.

Answer (score 1):

Your `requests.get()` returns an object. So, to make it readable, simply pass `.json()` method, like so:

```
def index(request):
    response = requests.get("https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json").json()
    return render(request, "index.html", {'response': response})
```

Comment: i have done it the way you showed, it doesn't display anything on the template now?

Answer (score 0):

Your requests.get() returns an object. So, to make it readable, simply pass .json() method, like so:

```
def index(request):
    response = requests.get("https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json").json()
    return render(request, "index.html", {'response': response})
```

remove title from item

```
{% story in response %}
   {{ story }}
{% endfor %}
```